# Update ubuntu server to the state of one week ago

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, update

I want to have the ubuntu updates on the production servers after they working one week on the staging servers. 
If I make `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` on the production servers after a week they are also getting updates which aren't tested one week on the staging servers.

Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant, but works: `apt-get update` on both types of servers, then `apt-get upgrade` on staging servers and `apt-get upgrade -d` (download only) on production servers. After week, if it's everything ok `apt-get upgrade` (but without `apt-get update`) on production.

Answer (score 0):

how i solve it is run a local mirror of the repositories you use and point the apt source files to that local repo and update off that. That way you have control of what goes on staging and production.

Comment: How can you keep local mirror sliding one week behind upstream sources?

Comment: run the rsync script by hand when you want to pull in updates to test on staging.